# 404 when accessing resource Flask-Restful

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404, flask-restful

```
from flask import g, request, session, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask import current_app as app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'this works'


from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from app.extensions import api


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'Hello': 'World'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/test')  # Getting a 404 for this route on http://127.0.0.1:5000/test
```

Extensions sets up the api variable:

```
api = Api()
api.init_app(app)
```

I cannot figure out why I get a 404 when trying to access an api resource?

Comment: have you tried it with a parameter?

Comment: Alternatively, your example done without parameters (matching your add_resource) and it appears to work just as expected. https://pastebin.com/yJy7F2At

Comment: Apologies, I was replacing my more complicated code with some from the docs and forgot the parameter. I have updated my code but the problem still persists for me.

Comment: The problem is that your code as shown doesn't reproduce the problem you're describing. You should write a [MCVE] that does.

Comment: Yes it does actually, just replace **api = Api(app)** with how I do it above (deferred init_app) and you will get the same issue. Anyhow I answered my question below.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, the problem seems to be that the below ordering is wrong. I must add resources before I init the api.

```
api = Api()
api.init_app(app)
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
```

Fix:

```
api = Api()
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.init_app(app)
```

This is quite strange given that e.g. SQLAlchemy needs to call init_app before it is used...

Comment: You could have done like this `app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app) api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/test')` (as per the docs).

Comment: In my code they aren't right beside each other as I am using an application factory

Comment: Also using a app factory and was about to punish my laptop until i found this answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Effectively in the docs the Fix is how they suggest to do. https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.init_app

Comment: Thanks you very much for this, saved my bacon. I thought I had messed it all up for a second.

Comment: Thank you for this, also using an app factory and couldn't figure out why I was getting the 404